# How to combine three keys as a hotkey with Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to combine `CapsLock Alt k` keys in a single hotkey, such as this:

```
CapsLock & !k:: Send !{Up}
```

This doesn't work because Autohotkey doesn't allow the combination of more than two keys except the modifier keys.

Searching for a [solution](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic41558.html) I found out that using scan codes in left hand side might be a work around, such as:

```
SC035 & !k:: Send !{Up}
```

I tested this solution too but this doesn't work properly neither. In this case, pressing `CapsLock+k` triggers the hotkey.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this?

```
Capslock & k:: 
GetKeyState, state, Alt
if state = D
SendInput !{Up}
Return
```

Comment: Thank you. This works really. But now there is a slight delay when using CapsLock combined with a key, such as "CapsLock&a::=". This delay is probably due to GetKeyState function, isn't it?

Comment: I tested, but could not recreate this delay. The script should be self-contained and not affect the performance of other scripts. Scripts that have GetKeyState to add a third hotkey (like the one I have above) will not behave exactly like scripts with normal hotkey setups and may prevent the script repeating as fast as usual. Hope that helps.

Comment: I prefer this more concise syntax and thought I'd share it with you: 

if not GetKeyState("Alt", "P")...

Modify according to your needs.
Cheers.