# How do I copy without formatting with Ctrl+Alt+C in AutoHotkey?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to define a keyboard shortcut such that if I press these **three keys simultaneously**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, AutoHotkey would copy the selected text **without formatting** to the clipboard.

Does AutoHotkey support this? If so, how? Most of what I have seen in the documentation at the official website relies on keyboard shortcuts made of **two** keystrokes, e.g.:

```
LControl + LAlt:: 
; Do something
```

Is there a way to do this with **three** keys? Also, how could I copy and remove the formatting from the selected text?

Answer (score 6):

See [How to combine three keys as a hotkey with Autohotkey?](https://superuser.com/questions/160881/how-to-combine-three-keys-as-a-hotkey-with-autohotkey) for the first half of your question.

As far as stripping formatting, it looks to be possible with something like this (from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98597/best-autohotkey-macros/2331297#2331297)):

```
Send ^c
clipboard = "%clipboard%"
; Remove space introduced by WORD
StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard,%A_SPACE%",", All
```

There's also [this AutoHotkey forum post](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic76636.html) about it.

EDIT: The following [is in the AutoHotkey documentation on Clipboard, ClipboardAll, and OnClipboardChange](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm):

> `clipboard = %clipboard%   ; Convert any copied files, HTML, or other formatted text to plain text.`

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be an AutoHotKey route, specifically?

For the exact thing you describe, I have found that [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) works really well in a wide variety of applications.

It's a tiny program, that you just add to your Startup folder, and then tell it what shortcut to use. (And turn off it's mildly annoying sound-effect, if you wish)

> The easiest way to use PureText is to simply use its hot-key to paste text instead of using the standard CTRL+V hot-key that is built into most Windows applications.  To configure PureText, right-click on its tray icon and choose "Options" from the pop-up menu.  The default hot-key is WINDOWS+V, but this can be changed.  In this Options window, you can also configure PureText to run each time you log into Windows.

See that page linked above, for details of what PureText will and won't do.