# on AHK how can I combine ALT+E+B into one hot key

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

Im having trouble creating this hotkey

In my program I use, I want to press Alt and e and B in order to do a command but I want to combine all that into one hotkey how would I do that?I just don't know the command to combine two letters

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine three keys as a hotkey with Autohotkey?](http://superuser.com/questions/160881/how-to-combine-three-keys-as-a-hotkey-with-autohotkey)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following method: Exclamation(!) for Alt key

**!eb::**
**Send** *type your commands here*
**return**