# How can a keypress on a specific keyboard be mapped to another key such as F24?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, arch-linux, obs-studio

I want to use an extra keyboard on **Linux** to control my OBS scenes. OBS has a way to setup keyboard shortcuts and so forth but only as a general key (it doesn't detect *which* keyboard the key is pressed on).

Is it possible to map a key, say `Num pad 1` to `F24` and then use that as the keyboard shortcut? I tried AutoKey but it doesn't have the ability to detect which keyboard it is, as far as I've seen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do when I need more keys than my keyboard has?](https://superuser.com/questions/1569979/what-to-do-when-i-need-more-keys-than-my-keyboard-has)

Comment: @Burgi Not really, that's for windows and there isn't such an app for linux AFAIK